# QT: View class hierarchy of any project (based on object instances or ... )

Tags: qt, class-design, qt-creator

Is there any way to view class hierarchy of any QT project graphically? (Project made by using QT-Creator.)
I have a big code bundle .. very badly managed code.
I need to start working with it. but first I need to study it nicely.

Some tool : Class viewer like one in VC++ (.NET)!?

I want the QT project class hierarchy, look like this one:
http://doc.trolltech.com/extras/qt43-class-chart.pdf
Or like this one: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/hierarchy.html

Keyword can be: class hierarchy explorer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) can create both graphical and textual class hierarchies. [This](http://moptaskmanager.sourceforge.net/hierarchy.html) is one I once made for a university project.

To generate the graphical hierarchy:

1. Make sure you have the `dot` program (from the [Graphiz](http://www.graphviz.org/) package) installed.
2. Set `GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY` and `HAVE_DOT` to `YES` in your `Doxyfile`.